# Conversion of date string to Date object

Tags: javascript

When I use

```
var today = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());
```

I get that `today` is `Tue Jan 14 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2020`

If I do `today.toDateString()` then I get `Tue Jan 14 2020`

If I store the last result to a cell how can I convert it back to what it was? (`Date` object)

Comment: Can you not create a new Date object? `new Date('Tue Jan 14 2020')` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below,

```
let today = new Date();
let todayInString = today.toDateString();
let originalDateForm = new Date(todayInString);
console.log(originalDateForm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are 4 ways to create a new [`Date`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) object in JavaScript:

1. `new Date()`
2. `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`
3. `new Date(milliseconds)`
4. `new Date(date string)`

The last one solves your problem:

```js
let now = new Date();
let today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
console.log(today);
let today2 = new Date(today.toString());
console.log(today2);
```